# Very low charging current on 24 V battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lead-acid

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3pZ8c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Recently, I bought 2 used lead-acid batteries for my UPS system. Each of them is 12 V, 45 Ah (NS60L). They also have terms like "Dry charge" and "Low maintenance" written on them.

I hooked them up to to an SMPS through a 1N5408 diode (the battery was keeping the SMPS light and fan on, even when the SMPS was disconnected from the mains). The voltage is set to 28 V (the two batteries are in series). When I start the SMPS the battery voltage quickly jumps to 28 V.

Initially there is a current spike of about 2 A, then it quickly drops to about 0.3 A. If I disconnect, the battery voltage drops. But after letting the SMPS run for some time and then disconnecting it, the battery voltage did seem to rise a bit. Is this an indicator that the batteries are no longer functional? The SMPS can deliver up to 10 A. At a charging rate of only 0.3 A it is going to take a long time for the batteries to charge fully.

Could anyone help me in this regard?

Comment: Adding a simple wiring schematic would help a lot.

Comment: @TirdadSadriNejad Thanks for pointing that out. I have added it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

An SMPS power supply is not a battery charger. It tries to push the voltage up to 28V and if 10A is not enough it will shut down, likely repeatedly starting and shutting down with the overcurrent protection.

You need a battery charger, not a SMPS power supply.

Comment: I understand however I was unable to find 24v battery charger that are in my budget. The ones I found were all for 12v.

Comment: @Hanzala19 Well it still does not change anything. You need a 24V battery charger to charge 24V batteries.

Comment: @Hanzala19 Why not charge the two batteries separately on the 12 V charger that you can afford to own?

Comment: @periblepsis I plan on attaching this to a UPS that requires 24v battery to function.

Comment: @Hanzala19 UPSes can charge batteries. Why not connect them to the UPS? Preferably charge both in 12V charger first.

Comment: The UPS provides only 0.5 A at max. It will take a really long time to fully recharge batteries once they are fully drained with that current. Therefore I want to add an additional charger to charge the batteries a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out battery voltages, chargers usually stop the charging process and try to "read" the battery voltage to see in what state it is. Adding a diode between them causes misinterpretation since the charger can't read the voltage back. That 0.3A charging current could be simply idle charging current or a limited current that tries to bring a battery alive.

Comment: I am using a normal SMPS not a battery charger. The SMPS does not have any current control like you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Fully charge each battery separately to 100 % SoC with a *battery charger*. Let it rest for 24 hours. Measure the voltage. Measure the internal resistance (4-wire 1 kHz AC). Measure the discharge capacity. Only then will you have enough evidence to say it's healthy.

The opposite is easier. If it does not hold voltage after being charged, it's bad. If it has very high internal resistance, it's bad.